# ERROR: dependency 'ROracle' is not available for package 'ora'

Tags: r, oracle, install.packages, roracle

I´m try to install "ora" package, so I use this command:

```
install.packages("ora")
```

However, it throws me the following error, where it indicates that the version of ROracle is not viable.

```
installing the source package 'ora'
  trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ora_2.0-1.tar.gz'
  Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 5815 bytes
  downloaded 5815 bytes

ERROR: dependency 'ROracle' is not available for package 'ora'
* removing 'C:/Users/samora/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library/ora'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ora’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\samora\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIxcR0T\downloaded_packages’
```

So I try to update it, but still after doing so, continue with the error.

Could you help me?

Comment: Those are pretty old packages, and it appears you won't be able to install them, at least not on Windows, the build is also failing [on CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_ROracle.html).